# Translate merge sort with linked lists from C to MIPS

Tags: c, pointers, mips, mergesort, translate

I'm trying to implement a merge sort algorithm in MIPS using linked lists. I'm basically trying to translate this code: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/
However, I'm having some issues. The sorted list is incomplete as if it had lost an entire recursive branch, for example, this is the linked list to sort:
4 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2
And the output is: 1 -> 2 -> 4. And then comes an error when I try to write the list to a file (Runtime exception at 0x004003fc: address out of range 0x00000000). I'm guessing that's because I expect to print 4 numbers, but I only have 3 numbers in the list.

I think where I need help is in the MergeSort function, as I don't COMPLETELY understand what it actually does pointer-wise. This is what I think it does:

It receives as a parameter a pointer to a pointer to the head of the list. Inside the function, it creates the "head" pointer, and it points to the VALUE of headRef (in this case, &head was passed on main, so now "head" inside the function has the address of head in the main). Then it declares two pointers, a and b (in MIPS this would be like doing a = 0, and b = 0? I can't "declare" registers). Then it checks if the list has 1 or 0 elements and returns if it does. Otherwise, it splits the list into two halves with FrontBackSplit(head, &a, &b), but this is the tricky par... this function doesn't return anything. Instead, it modifies the pointers "a" and "b", to make them point to the first half of the list, and the second half, respectively. In MIPS, I would think this as two return values $v0 and $v1. Then it sorts the list recursively, starting from the left, but once again, it doesn't return anything... it modifies the pointer "a" and "b". Finally, it changes the value of the pointer to the head of the list to make it point to the new sorted list.

Because of so many **ptr and &ptr values, I'm confused on what to save on the stack. This is what I ahve so far, regarding that function:

```
# void mergesort(node** headRef)
# input $a0: head of the list
mergesort:
    move    $t0, $s3                # node* head = headRef
    li      $t1, 0                  # node* a
    li      $t2, 0                  # node* b
    # if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
    beqz    $t0, mergesort_return
    lw      $t3, node_next($t0)     # $t3 = head->next
    beqz    $t3, mergesort_return

    move    $a0, $t0
    move    $a1, $t1
    move    $a2, $t2
    # save head and $ra
    addi    $sp, $sp, -8
    sw      $t0, 0($sp)
    sw      $ra, 4($sp)
    jal     frontbacksplit
    # restore head and $ra
    lw      $t0, 0($sp)
    lw      $ra, 4($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 8
    # save output results
    move    $t1, $v0                # a now points to the first half + 1 (if odd) of the list (frontRef)
    move    $t2, $v1                # b now points to the second half of the list (backRef)

    # save head, a, b and $ra
    addi    $sp, $sp, -16
    sw      $t0, 0($sp)
    sw      $t1, 4($sp)
    sw      $t2, 8($sp)
    sw      $ra, 12($sp)
    # mergesort(a)
    move    $a0, $t1
    jal     mergesort
    # restore registers and $ra
    lw      $t0, 0($sp)
    lw      $t1, 4($sp)
    lw      $t2, 8($sp)
    lw      $ra, 12($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 16

    # save head, a, b and $ra
    addi    $sp, $sp, -16
    sw      $t0, 0($sp)
    sw      $t1, 4($sp)
    sw      $t2, 8($sp)
    sw      $ra, 12($sp)
    # mergesort(b)
    move    $a0, $t2
    jal     mergesort
    # restore registers and $ra
    lw      $t0, 0($sp)
    lw      $t1, 4($sp)
    lw      $t2, 8($sp)
    lw      $ra, 12($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 16

    move    $a0, $t1
    move    $a1, $t2
    # save head, a, b and $ra
    addi    $sp, $sp, -16
    sw      $t0, 0($sp)
    sw      $t1, 4($sp)
    sw      $t2, 8($sp)
    sw      $ra, 12($sp)
    jal     sortedmerge
    # restore registers and $ra
    lw      $t0, 0($sp)
    lw      $t1, 4($sp)
    lw      $t2, 8($sp)
    lw      $ra, 12($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 16

    move    $s3, $v0        # s3 is the saved head of the original list declared in main

mergesort_return:
    jr      $ra
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I did it. This was a homework and hasn't been graded. I hope they don't think I copied it lol.

```
######### uses function frontbacksplit
######### WORKING
# mergesort
# input $a0: head of the list to merge
mergesort:
    li      $t0, 0      # head_one = NULL
    li      $t1, 0      # head_two = NULL
    # base case
    beqz    $a0, mergesort_return
    lw      $t2, node_next($a0)
    beqz    $t2, mergesort_return

    addi    $sp, $sp, -8
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)
    sw      $a0, 4($sp)

    # move $a0, $a0
    move    $a1, $t0
    move    $a2, $t1
    jal     frontbacksplit
    move    $t0, $v0
    move    $t1, $v1

    lw      $ra, 0($sp)
    lw      $a0, 4($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 8


    # mergesort(a)
    addi    $sp, $sp, -16
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)
    sw      $t0, 4($sp)
    sw      $t1, 8($sp)
    sw      $a0, 12($sp)

    move    $a0, $t0
    jal     mergesort   # mergesort(a)
    move    $t9, $v0

    lw      $ra, 0($sp)
    lw      $t0, 4($sp)
    lw      $t1, 8($sp)
    lw      $a0, 12($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 16

    # mergesort(b)
    addi    $sp, $sp, -20
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)
    sw      $t0, 4($sp)
    sw      $t1, 8($sp)
    sw      $a0, 12($sp)
    sw      $t9, 16($sp)

    move    $a0, $t1
    jal     mergesort   # mergesort(b)
    move    $t8, $v0

    lw      $ra, 0($sp)
    lw      $t0, 4($sp)
    lw      $t1, 8($sp)
    lw      $a0, 12($sp)
    lw      $t9, 16($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 20
    # t8 = a, t9 = b

    addi    $sp, $sp, -24
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)
    sw      $t0, 4($sp)
    sw      $t1, 8($sp)
    sw      $a0, 12($sp)
    sw      $t9, 16($sp)
    sw      $t8, 20($sp)

    move    $a0, $t8
    move    $a1, $t9
    jal     merge

    lw      $ra, 0($sp)
    lw      $t0, 4($sp)
    lw      $t1, 8($sp)
    lw      $a0, 12($sp)
    lw      $t9, 16($sp)
    lw      $t8, 20($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 24

    #move   $v0, $v0

    jr      $ra

mergesort_return:
    move    $v0, $a0
    jr      $ra 


######### WORKING
# input $a0: source node (list to split)
# input $a1: front ref (a) $s4
# input $a2: back ref (b)  $s5
# output $v0: frontRef
# output $v1: backRef
frontbacksplit:
    # $a0 = node* source, $a1 = node* frontRef, $a2 = node* backRef
    move    $t0, $a0                # $t0 = source
    move    $t1, $a1                # $t1 = frontRef
    move    $t2, $a2                # $t2 = backRef

    li      $t3, 0                  # node* fast;
    li      $t4, 0                  # node* slow;
    # if(source == NULL)
    beqz    $t0, frontbacksplit_sorted
    lw      $t5, node_next($t0)     # $t5 = source->next
    # if(source->next == NULL)
    beqz    $t5, frontbacksplit_sorted
    # else
    move    $t4, $t0                # slow = source
    lw      $t3, node_next($t0)     # fast = source->next

frontbacksplit_while:
    # while(fast != NULL)
    beqz    $t3, frontbacksplit_endwhile
    lw      $t3, node_next($t3)     # fast = fast->next
    # if(fast != NULL)
    beqz    $t3, frontbacksplit_while
    lw      $t4, node_next($t4)     # slow = slow->next
    lw      $t3, node_next($t3)     # fast = fast->next
    j       frontbacksplit_while

frontbacksplit_endwhile:
    move    $t1, $t0                # frontRef = source
    lw      $t2, node_next($t4)     # backRef = slow->next
    sw      $zero, node_next($t4)   # slow->next = NULL

    move    $v0, $t1
    move    $v1, $t2
    j       frontbacksplit_end

frontbacksplit_sorted:
    move    $v0, $t0                # frontRef = source
    li      $v1, 0                  # backRef = NULL

frontbacksplit_end:
    jr      $ra


############ WORKING
# input $a0: head of the first list
# input $a1: head of the second list
# output $v0: pointer to the head of the merged-sorted list
merge:
    beqz    $a0, merge_return2
    beqz    $a1, merge_return1
    li      $t3, 0          # head_three = NULL

    lw      $t0, node_int($a0)
    lw      $t1, node_int($a1)

    addi    $sp, $sp, -16
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)
    sw      $a0, 4($sp)
    sw      $a1, 8($sp)
    sw      $t3, 12($sp)

    bge     $t0, $t1, merge_else

    # if head_one->num < head_two->num
    lw      $a0, node_next($a0)
    # $a1 already has head_two
    jal     merge
    move    $t0, $v0        # ptr = merge(head_one->next, head_two)
    # restore values
    lw      $ra, 0($sp)
    lw      $a0, 4($sp)
    lw      $a1, 8($sp)
    lw      $t3, 12($sp)

    move    $t3, $a0
    sw      $t0, node_next($t3)
    move    $v0, $t3
    addi    $sp, $sp, 16
    jr      $ra 

merge_else:
    # $a0 already has head_one
    lw      $a1, node_next($a1)
    jal     merge
    move    $t0, $v0        # ptr = merge(head_one->next, head_two)
    # restore values
    lw      $ra, 0($sp)
    lw      $a0, 4($sp)
    lw      $a1, 8($sp)
    lw      $t3, 12($sp)

    move    $t3, $a1
    sw      $t0, node_next($t3)
    move    $v0, $t3
    addi    $sp, $sp, 16
    jr      $ra

merge_return1:
    move    $v0, $a0
    jr      $ra

merge_return2:
    move    $v0, $a1
    jr      $ra
```

I know it's quite messy but it works :P.

Comment: Congratulations on finding the solution yourself. For instructional purposes for other users that might have a similar problem, it might be nice for you to edit your answer here to detail what you fixed from your original question. Also, other problems you encountered [and fixed], etc. As well as what you learned and/or improved upon.

Comment: I'll do it as soon as I have more time :D. Maybe next week.